# NameError: name 'DmozItem' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Still getting to grips with Scapy and been following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_overview.htm) tutorial. Having a little trouble following however as I am getting the following: `NameError: name 'DmozItem' is not defined` when I run this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Item, Field

class QuotesItems(scrapy.Item):
    area_name = scrapy.Field()
    room_type = scrapy.Field()
    period = scrapy.Field()
    duration_weekly = scrapy.Field()
    guide_total = scrapy.Field()
    amenities = scrapy.Field()


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "not_quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.unitestudents.com/',
            ]

    # Step 1
    def parse(self, response):
        for city in response.xpath('//select[@id="frm_homeSelect_city"]/option[not(contains(text(),"Select your city"))]/text()').extract(): # Select all cities listed in the select (exclude the "Select your city" option)
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin("/"+city), callback=self.parse_citypage)

    # Step 2
    def parse_citypage(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="property-header"]/h3/span/a/@href').extract(): #Select for each property the url
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_unitpage)


    # Step 3
    def parse_unitpage(self, response):
        for final in response.xpath('//div/div/div[@class="content__btn"]/a/@href').extract(): #Select final page for data scrape
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(final), callback=self.parse_final)

    #Step 4 
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//html/body/div'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['area_name'] = sel.xpath('//div/ul/li/a/span/text()').extract()
            item['room_type'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/div/h1/span/text()').extract()
            item['period'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/form/h4/span/text()').extract()
            item['duration_weekly'] = sel.xpath('//html/body/div/div/section/div/form/div/div/em/text()').extract()
            item['guide_total'] = sel.xpath('//html/body/div/div/section/div/form/div/div/p/text()').extract()
            item['amenities'] = sel.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li/p/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

I have set up my items.py file as:

```
class DmozItem(Item):
    area_name = Field()
    room_type = Field()
    period = Field()
    duration_weekly = Field()
    guide_total = Field()
    amenities = Field()
    pass
```

Not really sure where I am going wrong on this one?

Comment: is DmozItem() imported ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `QuotesItems` which has the same definition as `DmozItem` and is in the same file as `QuotesSpider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import **DmozItem**

```
from YourFolderName.items import DmozItem
```